# Enmapbox Spatial Prewitt Filter

Tags: qgis-processing

I want to create a magnetic first vertical derivative raster from a csv file containing z=magnetic total field, x= easting, y= northing.  I am told Enmapbox/ Spatial Prewitt filter will do this and I have tried but cant get the boxes filled correctly.